# how to get values from linked table using grouping key

Tags: jquery, linq, grouping

I have to tables arAbonamenty and arKlienci. Every item in arAbonamnety is linked to arKlienci.

Please look to code below. Using first temp_query I can see values from second table ( arKlienci ), but if I group records in arAbonamenty I cannot refer to items from arKlienci

```
var temp_query = from myAbonamenty in myNexo_ARWALEntities.ArAbonamenty
            where (myAbonamenty.czy_fa_auto_na_początku_miesiąca == true)
            select new
            {
                klientId=myAbonamenty.id_klient,
                klientId_nabywca = myAbonamenty.ArKlienci.Nexo_klient_nabywca,   
                klientId_odbiorca = myAbonamenty.ArKlienci.Nexo_klient_odbiorca
            };



var query = from myAbonamenty in myNexo_ARWALEntities.ArAbonamenty
             where (myAbonamenty.czy_fa_auto_na_początku_miesiąca == true)
             group myAbonamenty by myAbonamenty.id_klient into myAboGrupowane
             select new
             {
                klientId = myAboGrupowane.Key,
                abonament = myAboGrupowane
             };

foreach (var AboGrupowane in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(AboGrupowane.klientId);
    /// here I want to refer to klientID_nabywca and klientId_odbiorca
    foreach (var myAbonamenty in AboGrupowane.abonament)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myAbonamenty.Asortymenty.Id);
    }
}
```

I want to refer to these items where I have put comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the same `klientId` implies the same `ArKlienci` link, you just need to access one of the group:

```
var query = from myAbonamenty in myNexo_ARWALEntities.ArAbonamenty
             where (myAbonamenty.czy_fa_auto_na_początku_miesiąca == true)
             group myAbonamenty by myAbonamenty.id_klient into myAboGrupowane
             let arKlienci = myAboGrupowane.First()
             select new
             {
                klientId = myAboGrupowane.Key,
                abonament = myAboGrupowane,
                klientId_nabywca = arKlienci.Nexo_klient_nabywca,   
                klientId_odbiorca = arKlienci.Nexo_klient_odbiorca                 
            };
```

I used `let` to avoid calling `First` twice.

Comment: Thanks , your code helped me to find a solution ( but it didn't work ).

Comment: What didn't work? I don't see why you would need `FirstOrDefault()` as it shouldn't be possible to have an empty group from `group ... by`.

Comment: klientId_nabywca = arKlienci.Nexo_klient_nabywca did not work , I change it to klientId_nabywca = myAboFirst.ArKlienci.Nexo_klient_nabywca , the same with odbiorca

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer helped me to find a solution:

```
var query = from myAbonamenty in myNexo_ARWALEntities.ArAbonamenty
             where (myAbonamenty.czy_fa_auto_na_początku_miesiąca == true)
             group myAbonamenty by myAbonamenty.id_klient into myAboGrupowane
             let myAboFirst = myAboGrupowane.FirstOrDefault()
             select new
             {
                klientId = myAboGrupowane.Key,
                klientId_nabywca = myAboFirst.ArKlienci.Nexo_klient_nabywca,
                klientId_odbiorca = myAboFirst.ArKlienci.Nexo_klient_odbiorca,
                abonament = myAboGrupowane
             };

foreach (var AboGrupowane in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(AboGrupowane.klientId);
    Console.WriteLine(AboGrupowane.klientId_nabywca);
    foreach (var myAbonamenty in AboGrupowane.abonament)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myAbonamenty.Asortymenty.Id);
    }
}
```